# How do I delete a stored procedure in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures

How do I delete a stored procedure in Postgresql?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
DROP FUNCTION name(arguments);
```

Comment: I didn't know I had to specify the arguments, but that makes sense.
Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I was able to drop a **Stored Procedure** by below command:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS <schema-name>.<procedure-name>(all-arguments);
```

Example:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS public.my_procedure(empname character varying);
```

Answer (score 3):

you can delete it even without arguments name

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS name;
```

Comment: It is possible to have a procedure with same name and different set of arguments, so it's better to give arguments while dropping to be more precise.

Answer (score 2):

PostgreSQL 11 introduced [stored procedures](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/static/sql-createprocedure.html). Plus it adds new syntax **[DROP ROUTINE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/static/sql-droproutine.html)**:

> *DROP ROUTINE [ IF EXISTS ] name [ ( [ [ argmode ] [ argname ] argtype [, ...] ] ) ] [, ...]*
>
> **DROP ROUTINE removes the definition of an existing routine, which can be an aggregate function, a normal function, or a procedure.**
>
> ```
> DROP ROUTINE IF EXISTS foo(integer);
> ```
>
> This command conforms to the SQL standard, with these PostgreSQL extensions:
>
> - The standard only allows one routine to be dropped per command.
> - The IF EXISTS option
> - The ability to specify argument modes and names
> - Aggregate functions are an extension.